# could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com after fresh install of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, server, dns, archive, resolv.conf

I can open *Firefox* and it works well but when
I try to run

```
sudo apt update
```

it returns

```
could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com
```

I've tried changing dns server in wifi settings to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`
and also tried editing the  `resolv.conf` 
the output of ip route is

```
default via 192.168.18.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 2600
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000
192.168.0.0/16 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.18.120 metric 600
```

the output of systemd-resolve --status has a lot of details but i think problem is with wlan whose details are

```
Current scope : DNS
LLMNR setting : Yes
multicastdns setting : no
DNSSEC setting : no
DNSSEC supported : no
DNS servers : 192.168.18.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


# dig @192.168.18.1 archive.ubuntu.com
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.18.1 archive.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out
; no servers could be reached  

# dig @8.8.8.8 archive.ubuntu.com gives
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 archive.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out
; no servers could be reached


# sudo nmap -p 53 -sU 192.168.18.1|grep -P '(open|closed|filtered)'
53/udp open|filtered domain
```

`sudo nmap -p 53 -sU 8.8.8.8|grep -P '(open|closed|filtered)'` outputs
nothing

Comment: Edit your question to add the output of `ip route` command and `systemd-resolve --status`. This will help us to understand the problem

Comment: what is the output of `dig @192.168.18.1 archive.ubuntu.com` and `dig @8.8.8.8 archive.ubuntu.com`.  dig comes with **dnsutils** and should be installed. I fnot go to packages.ubuntu.com grab the package and install it with `dpkg -i`

Comment: Edit your question to include that and remove the comment please. Add the output of  the 2 commands.

Comment: Check the configuration of firefox. It should use a proxy or something. Check your firewall if you have any. What is the output of `sudo nmap -p 53 -sU 192.168.18.1|grep -P '(open|closed|filtered)'` and  `sudo nmap -p 53 -sU 8.8.8.8|grep -P '(open|closed|filtered)'`

Comment: You failed the `nmap command`. This is port 53 not 3. Retry again. And use the `{}` icon above to properly format the output. Thanks

Comment: @solsTiCe oh ok i don't know if it was a typing mistake but i have added those outputs and sorry for the improper formatting i'm a noob

Comment: @solsTiCe any idea what should i do sir ?

Comment: What is the network config of firefox ?

Comment: @solsTiCe it is set to manual http proxy 192.162.0.103 port 3128

Comment: You have a weird network setup. I don't know what to tell you. If someone else oculd help ?

Comment: @KhushalSahni did you manage to solve it?